# Tweepy api binder and python properties

Tags: python, tweepy

I've been digging around the tweepy source code trying to get a feel for how everything is designed. I'm a little confused with the `API` class and `bind_api` function. The tweepy source can be found here: https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy

1) Why is almost every api call a property? What is this actually doing and what benefit does it provide?

2) How is `bind_api` getting the arguments fed into each api call? For example,

```
@property
def get_status(self):
    """ :reference: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/show/%3Aid
        :allowed_param:'id'
    """
    return bind_api(
        api=self,
        path='/statuses/show.json',
        payload_type='status',
        allowed_param=['id']
    )
```

`get_status` takes no arguments in its definition, but calling api.get_status(id='123') works fine. I'm curious what is happening here. I assume this relates to my first question.

3) Following this same format tweepy is using with `bind_api`, how can one get the keyword arguments that are fed to an api call? For example if I want to just print "No id supplied" when no `id='value'` keyword is supplied to `get_status`, how would I go about that?

Thanks for any help. Hopefully I was clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not thinking when I asked this the other day.

`bind_api` is returning a function. This function is then called when that property is called. That is why each api call is a `@property` which also answers my second question.